# get queryset values that fall in a list

Tags: python, django

i have model data as:
**id    | name

1     | abcd

2     | xyz

.....**

and a list as **[1,5,8]**
now i want to retrieve all names whose id falls in the list using a queryset, how do i do that in django, do i have to use a loop, or is there a better way to do so in django, say model name is **X**
qs=X.objects.filter(some custom filter here).**values('name')**
i need the names where id is one in the list

Comment: `qs=X.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,5,8]).values('name')` ?

Comment: thankyou @Rakesh this will help me lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
qs=X.objects.filter(id__in = [1,8,10]).values('name')
```